Jquery find and replace an attribute not working
I'm trying to fix some accessibility errors in a new wordpress site by fixing alt tags. I created a new js file called "fixes.js" and included the following:
$('body img').each(function() {
    if ( ! $(this).attr('alt'))
        $(this).attr('alt', '');
});

$('body img').each(function() {
    if ( ! $(this).attr('alt', 'Blog Image'))
        $(this).attr('alt', '');
});

I can see the file is being loaded into the page, but it's not doing it's job, as you can see here:
https://axxs.io/articles/
Any ideas what the issue is?

What did you intend to test with the second if statement? That condition is never going to be true, because attr(x, y) returns a jQuery object, and objects are truthy, and so the negation is always false.

Secondly, have you waited for the document to load before searching for img elements?

I suspect you mean if ($(this).attr('alt') != 'Blog Image'). .attr('alt', 'Blog Image') sets the attribute, it doesn't compare the attribute.

What's the point of the first loop? A nonexistent alt attribute is the same as an empty string.

Answer to question one: find any image on a page that doesn't have an alt attribute at all, eg:  and add an empty one like  Answer to question two: So are you saying I need to wrap the code in a document.ready statement? My Jquery is REALLY rusty. Answer to question three: find all images with the alt text of "Blog Image" and replace them with an empty alt like so: change  to 



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // Find images without an alt attribute and add a blank alt attribute
        $('body img:not([alt])').attr('alt', '');

        // Find images with alt attribute equal to "Blog Image" and replace with a blank alt attribute
        $('body img[alt="Blog Image"]').attr('alt', '');
    });
</script>



